# Dotfuscator throws 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: dotfuscator, baml

I am working on a .NET Sdk project that uses WPF.

I am trying to obfuscate the binary using Dotfuscator and the build process return the following message.

```
Warning: No debugging symbols found for module 'MyAssembly.resources.dll'.

Processing Check attributes...

Analyzing Markup...
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in "MyAssembly.g.resources\folder/XamlScreen.baml"
Build Error.
```

The XamlScreen.baml does exist and is output to a custom intermediate folder that is defined in directory.build.props. How to configure the dotfuscator project o also search for the intermediate folder?